# Complex conidtions in bash where the return value of executables are being evaluated

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, return-value, encapsulation

We can make somewhat complex condition statements inside `[[ ]]` or `(( ))` type brackets.

e.g.:

```
a=3;b=4;c=4
if [[ 1 == 1 && ( ( $a == $b && 1 == 1 ) || ( $b == $c && 2 == 2)) ]]; 
then echo yes; 
else echo no; 
fi
```

if we consider an equivalent to this using executable commands that return an error, I'm not sure how to proceed. In the instance of a chain of 'and's, it is trivial:

```
if echo hello | grep -q "h" && stat /etc/os-release 2>/dev/null; 
then echo yes; 
else echo no; 
fi
```

What if I have some branches though? like in the first example that I gave.

The question essentially boils down to how do I create groups of commands? The parenthesis that I used in the first condition seem to only work inside of the `[[ ]]` block.

As a side question, is my approach here silly?
I know that I could do what I want with a bunch of 'if' statements, but I thought that would look ugly.

The essence of what I'm trying to do is to perform a series of checks to be done sequentially and with one branch, based on the evaluation of a variable.

Many thanks

Comment: *that would look ugly* And that single, complex statement on one line that's so long it causes the creation of a horizontal scroll bar is what?  And instead of `$a` you'd replace with longer actual commands?  Who is teaching you to stuff so much **ugly** garbage on one line like that?  No one is ever going to be able to understand code with so much crammed into one line.  "Brevity of code" is utter nonsense. You want **understandable** code, and you don't care what it looks like.

Comment: Your example code is too far away from what you really want to know, I suspect. I see `1 == 1 &&` and I can't take the rest of it seriously. Please rethink your approach to your question

Comment: You create groups of commands with [the shell's grouping constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping). You create groups of *expressions* with parentheses just as you have shown.

Comment: And remember that you can nest `if` blocks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I have some branches though?

```
if [[ 1 == 1 && ( ( $a == $b && 1 == 1 ) || ($b == $c && 2 == 2) ) ]];
```

To clarify, there are no `(( ))` "type" brackets here, ie. there is no arithmetical expansion happening here and the `let` builtin is not executed. Now let's substitute `1 == 1` to `true` and `$a == $b` to "cmd1" and `$b == $c` to `cmd2`, we can:

```
if true && { { cmd1 && true; } || { cmd2 && true; }; }; then
```

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping), you have two ways to group commands:

> ()
>   ( list )
>   Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a
>   subshell environment to be created (see Command Execution
>   Environment), and each of the commands in list to be executed in that
>   subshell. Since the list is executed in a subshell, variable
>   assignments do not remain in effect after the subshell completes.
>
> {}
>   { list; }
>   Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes
>   the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is
>   created. The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

There is no syntactical difference between condition in the if and the expression inside `then .. fi` clause - both are expressions and are parsed as bash commands. So you can nest them:

```
if
    if true; then
        cmd1
    else
        cmd2
    fi
then
    cmd3
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had in mind to go back and tidy up my question, but it seems it was done for me. I found @glenn jackman's comment helpful and used the ( stuff ) construct. Though the issue with scope of variables hit me and I needed to do some reworking. The { list; } construct with a single element might have been a better way to go actually. I'll think of redoing that.